# Insert the battery in a notebook connected to electricity?

Tags: laptop, power-management

I use to work on the netbook (Asus X53S) with no battery using the electricity cable.

Sometimes it happened that I need to move the notebook and I would like to know if is it possible to insert the battery to avoid stop and restart.

Comment: It should be possible under most notebooks, but your title is not accurate as a notebook without battery is not "charging". I was curious about a notebook with 2 batteries...

Comment: @NuTTyX you are right. Now it is corrected

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I work with no battery to preserve it and I do never try to insert the battery while the notebook is on and connected to electricity

Comment: Well TRY IT... it's the easiest way to find out.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I prefer to ask it on a website where there are a lot of users that are more expert than me. So it easy to do not make mistake with the notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In my experience*, most laptops allow the battery to be inserted while the computer is powered on. Its very similar to attaching the AC lead while its powered on. There should not be an issue. I could not find anything about your model stating it should not be done. So, go ahead.

**THE RISK IS**; I have learned of corrupting data or damaged hard drive because the laptop gets dropped while it is running, simply because inserting the battery with the laptop open can be cumbersome.

- If you do not have time to shutdown the computer before inserting the
  battery, just be careful.
- If you have time to shut down, it is better to be safe than sorry.